# AngularJS passing function to the modal, "this" is not referring to the controller I want

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issue while trying to use function of the **parent controller** of my **modal**.

From the **parent controller** I open a **modal**, in the **modal** I do actions and when I click on a button I want to use the function **parentOnChange** of the **parent controller**.

To do this I pass the **parentOnChange** function of the **parent controller** through the resolve function of **IModalService**.

In **parentOnChange** I use other functions of the **parent controller**, the problem is : keyword "**this**" in **parentOnChange** is not referring the **parent controller** but to the **modal controller**, so it trigger an error :

```
this.oneFunction is not a function
```

I can't figure out how to solve this :)

Any help would be appreciated ;)

*Code is written in angular@1.6.6 with typescript*

Here is a simplified example :

**The parent controller**

```
export class Controller implements IComponentController {
    public static $inject: string[] = [
        '$uibModal'
    ];

    constructor(
        private readonly $uibModal: IModalService
    ) { }

    private openContextMenu(object: MyInterface) {
        const modal = this.$uibModal.open({
            component: 'myContextMenuModal',
            resolve: {
                object: () => object,
                onChange: () => this.parentOnChange
            }
        });
    }

    public parentOnChange(object: MyInterface) {
        console.log(this);
        this.oneFunction();
       this.twoFunction(object);
    }

    public oneFunction() {
        ...
    }

    public twoFunction(object: MyInterface) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**The modal**

```
export class Controller {
    // Bindings
    public readonly close: (data: any) => void;
    public readonly dismiss: () => void;
    public readonly resolve: {
        object: MyInterface,
        onChange(object: MyInterface) : void
    };

    public object: MyInterface;
    public onChange: (object: MyInterface) => void;

    public button_Click(): void {
        ...
        this.Change(this.object);
        ...
    }
}
export default {
    template: htmlTemplate,
    controller: Controller,
    bindings: {
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not Angularjs, to me it looks more like Angular 2 / 4.

Comment: That's angular@1.6.6 with typescript

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually never thought of using it with TS :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot figure out how to solve it, neither got time to create a plunker...

Anyway I did it a different way :

**The parent controller**

```
export class Controller implements IComponentController {
    ...
    constructor(
    private $scope: IScope,
    private readonly $uibModal: IModalService
) {
    this.$scope.$on('myEventName', this.parentOnChange.bind(this));
}
    ...

    private openContextMenu(object: MyInterface) {
        const modal = this.$uibModal.open({
            component: 'myContextMenuModal',
            scope: this.$scope, // Passing current scope to the modal
            resolve: {
                object: () => object,
                onChange: () => this.parentOnChange
            }
        });
    }

    public parentOnChange(_event: IAngularEvent, args: MyInterface[]) {
        console.log(args[0]); // this is my object send by the modal
        this.oneFunction();
        this.twoFunction(object);
    }

    public oneFunction() {
        ...
    }

    public twoFunction(object: MyInterface) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**The modal**

```
export class Controller {
    ...
    // Bindings
    public readonly close: (data: any) => void;
    public readonly dismiss: () => void;
    public readonly resolve: {
        object: MyInterface
    };

    public object: MyInterface;

    public button_Click(): void {
        ...
        this.$scope.$emit('myEventName', [this.object]);
        ...
    }
}
```